# ASP.NET & SQL Server: won't update but will append/insert

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am using a database-first approach with a custom html helper to get a state of a checkbox using ajax (without using form in the view). I have two tables:

- Tbl_1 -> Id, state (true or false), name (name of checkbox)
- Tbl_2 -> Id, user_guid, timestamp, Tbl_1Id (foreign_key)

When I do insert operations, it does without any problem but when I try to update it (based upon the logged in user as it also gets GUID, the table gets appended/inserted with new data).

My controller:

```
public ActionResult SetState(checkboxstate cbstate)
{
    var UserId = new Guid(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("sub").Value);
    var ent = new StartopDatabaseEntities();

    var cbs = ent.checkboxstates.Where(w => w.Name == "World").FirstOrDefault();

    if (cbs == null) // when there are no records in the database
    { 
        ent.checkboxstates.Add(cbstate); 
        ent.checkboxstateUpdates.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == cbstate.Id);

        var cbsOp = new checkboxstateUpdates();
        cbsOp.timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        cbsOp.user_guid = UserId;
        cbstate.checkboxstateUpdates.Add(cbsOp);               
        ent.SaveChanges();               
    } // record in database, update (I've only one user now, so has to update only this one) 
    else
    {
        var cbsOp = new checkboxstateUpdates();   // declare in global
        var chc = new checkboxstate();            // to be declared in global
        var newCbs = ent.checkboxstateUpdates.Include(c => c.checkboxstate).ToList();

        foreach (var u in newCbs)
        {
            if(u.user_guid==UserId && u.CheckboxStateId == u.checkboxstate.Id)
            {
                chc.state = cbstate.state;
                chc.name = cbstate.name;
                ent.checkboxstates.Add(chc);
                cbsOp.Tidspunkt = DateTime.Now;
                cbsOp.OpdateretAfBruger = UserId;
                ent.checkboxstateUpdates.Add(cbsOp);
                ent.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain please why it's not updating but appending/inserting same data with a new Id (primary key)? I have a simple view where Ajax sends a call to the controller with the state and name of the checkbox. I have also tried

```
Db.Entry(obj).state = EntityState.Modified
```

without any help

Comment: Is the `else` block supposed to be the update?  You're not updating anything, you're creating new records and calling `.Add()` to add them to the data.

Comment: What is the error you get? is it a database exception? You need to provide any errors, stack trace to give you an answer.

Comment: Yes David, else is for updating. Can you please explain me how do I fix it.

Comment: @Dhanuka777- There is no error, it just won't update rather it adds.

Comment: @rkun: Well what are you trying to update?  You have a `cbs` object you got from the data, but you never update it.  It's not really clear to me what you're trying to modify here.

Comment: You have two tables. In the else part which table you want to update? Both the tables or only one of them? if one of them then which one of them? What is the use case here? How the tables are related?

Comment: I'm trying to update the new 'state' of the button i.e, true or false and 'timestamp' which has to be current. In my code, I also tried to update 'name' (of checkbox) and 'user_guid' but that is not necessary for this code.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya- Both, on table_1 'state' and on table_2 - 'timestamp'...though in this code I've tried to update other things but they are not necessary.

Comment: @rkun: It's not really clear to me what the structure of your data is or means, but basically anywhere that you create a `new someClass()` and add that object to the data it's going to add a *new* record to the data.  To update an existing record, instead of creating a `new someClass()`, get the instance of that object from `ent` and update the properties on that object.  When you call `SaveChanges()`, updates you made to objects pulled from `ent` will be updated in the database.

Comment: @David - That means this is wrong - var cbsOp = new checkboxstateUpdates();            var chc = new checkboxstate(); I should make an instance of the object from 'ent' right?

Comment: @rkun: Basically, yes.  An update to an existing record involves updating that existing record, not creating a new one.

Comment: @David - Nice, that make sense. Any suggestion with code snippet?

Comment: @rkun - For updates you need to assign the values to existing ones but you are calling Add() method.

Comment: @radkan - Learned a lesson. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not written the code for the logic which want to achieve..

I am not clear on the logic of if block also but the else part can be fixed as following.

```
var newCbs = ent.checkboxstateUpdates.Include(c => c.checkboxstate).Where(u.user_guid == UserId).FirstOrDefault();

if(newCbs != null) {
    newCbs.checkboxstate.state = cbstate.state;
    newCbs.checkboxstate.name = cbstate.name;
    newCbs.Tidspunkt = DateTime.Now;
    newCbs.OpdateretAfBruger = UserId;

    ent.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Partially correct solution as he did not get the whole logic but a good inspiration.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with the help from @David & @Chetan:

I did some modify in the code as per David:

```
u.checkboxstate.state=cbstate.state;
u.checkboxstate.name=cbstate.name;
u.timestamp=DateTime.Now;
ent.saveChanges();
```

I was using the wrong logic i.e. getting instance of the class rather than the 'ent' object. Thanks guys for the help.